# Simple complex number proof

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to clear up a few steps I am not comfortable with in my lecturers notes.

Suppose either $\vert z\vert =1$ or $\vert w\vert =1$. Then $\vert z\vert\vert w\vert\not=1$. Hence $\overline{z}w\not=1$.

How do we deduce the final step?

Comment: By "either...or"  I assume you are referring to the exclusive or (implying exactly one of $|z|$ or $|w|$ are of unit norm).  Consider the contrapositive.  What happens if $\overline{z}w=1$ instead?  If you take the modulus of each side, you get $1=|1|=|\overline{z}w|=|\overline{z}||w|=|z||w|$, a contradiction

Comment: If $\bar{z} w = 1$ then $1 =|\bar{z} w | = |\bar{z} | | w |   = |z | | w | $. One of the two terms in the product is 1 so the other one is 1 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\overline{z}w=1$, then $1=\overline{\overline{z}w}=z\overline{w}$
and now $1=1\cdot 1=(\overline{z}w)(z\overline{w})=|zw|^2$, so $|zw|=1$